# Mule Cache - Expiry

Tags: caching, mule

How do i setup an expiry time for the cache entries in mule ? I am setting up a keyExpression based cache on the incoming requests, like this:

```
   <ee:object-store-caching-strategy name="UserAuth-CachingStrategy" keyGenerationExpression="#[message.inboundProperties.'authorization']" doc:name="Caching Strategy">
```

The cache is supposed to hit an external WS and the results are supposed to be cached for 5 minutes. If i set an 'in-memory' store with a TTL for let's say 5 minutes, mule isn't honoring this request. Irrespective of the value in TTL, mule always hits the actual external ws once every 3-4 requests. If i don't set any value for TTL, then the cache never expires. how do i properly set a cache for an 'in-memory' cache in mule ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using ObjectStore , you can easily set as given in the following using spring properties and referring your caching strategy to it  :-
http://ricston.com/blog/cache-scope-ehcache/

You can also use managed-store as following :-

```
<ee:object-store-caching-strategy nname="UserAuth-CachingStrategy" keyGenerationExpression="#[message.inboundProperties.'authorization']" doc:name="Caching Strategy">
<managed-store storeName="myNonPersistentManagedObjectStore" maxEntries="-1" entryTTL="20000" expirationInterval="5000"/>
</ee:object-store-caching-strategy>
```

Comment: Is the expirationInterval in ms?

Comment: @AnirbanSenChowdhary What effect does maxEntries="-1" have. Why is it in the negative